# How can I find out what motherboard is in my computer?

Tags: windows-7, motherboard

I want to find out the exact model of my computer's motherboard so that I can see what sort of memory chip, graphics cards and other components it supports.

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit.

Comment: You are better off opening the case to get the motherboard model number and Revision number, then go the the manufacturers site to look for drivers.

Answer (score 287, accepted):

Daveb was moving in the right direction. You need to type the following within a command prompt:

```
wmic baseboard get product,Manufacturer,version,serialnumber
```

This will provide you with the maker of the motherboard, model number, and serial number.

Comment: +1 for an answer which does not require third party software.

Comment: And to get bios version use: wmic bios get smbiosbiosversion

Comment: Oh my goodness, this gives exactly what I have been looking for. And nothing online has helped. It doesn't show up in MSinfo32 or System.

Answer (score 38):

Yet another option to launch `dxdiag` tool from the start menu:

[image]

Comment: fastest, easiest no third-party software needed

Comment: This didn't work on my ASUS mobo.

Comment: @Gerard You need DirectX

Comment: Unfortunately didn't help for me.  Both the *System Manufacturer* and *System Model* say "To Be Filled By O.E.M." on my machine.

Comment: System Model showed up as just "All Series", but txyoji's answer worked

Answer (score 21):

[CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) can identifiy mainboards, among other components. I think that should do it.

Answer (score 16):

[Belarc Advisor](http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html) will tell you what type of motherboard you have.

Answer (score 13):

Open the Command Prompt (cmd) and type:

> wmic cpu get name,CurrentClockSpeed,MaxClockSpeed

This command will tell you the system motherboard (that happen to be the name) and its UUID.

> wmic bios get name,serialnumber,version

This will tells you the name if your BIOS, current version and its serial number if there is any.

Technet has a [useful reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx) for WMIC commands.

Comment: wmic cpu get name,CurrentClockSpeed,MaxClockSpeed

seems to list - CurrentClock Speed - MaxClockSpeed and the Processor Name/Model

Comment: None of those give the motherboard model.

Answer (score 9):

[Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy) is an Advanced System Information tool for your PC.

[image]

(It is made by the same company that designed CCleaner)

Answer (score 7):

Another option: I happen to like **[SIW - System Information for Windows](http://www.gtopala.com/)**

[image: ahh nais pigsure]

Comment: Note: There is no longer a free version for download.

Comment: I use http://www.hwinfo.com/ . It's freeware.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a desktop system that was built from parts: Open the case. The motherboard brand and model number is printed on it.

If you have a laptop, or purchased a desktop from a OEM such as Dell: there's not really a motherboard model on the thing, you're going to have to go with the computer's model number.

Answer (score 1):

Use Intel's online System Identification Utility:

http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/idyp

Comment: Does this work with non-Intel boards?

Answer (score 0):

[CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) works too, has a 64 bit version.

Answer (score 0):

There are several products you can install to get this information, but the one I've used in the past is Belarc Advisor (useful for auditing):

http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html

Comment: Just be careful when you post these profiles on the web, they contain your software serial numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The motherboard itself must comply with a standard called DMI. This provides information such as the motherboard model, BIOS version, the number of RAM sticks, their capacity and speed, and basically anything else that is related to your motherboard.

There are two popular programs that can retrieve this information. CPU-Z and dmidecode.  While CPU-Z is a user-friendly alternative, dmidecode has the advantage of being a nice, clean tool that works on practically all operating systems.

- [dmidecode download for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/dmidecode.htm)

Answer (score 0):

```
wmic csproduct get name,identifyingnumber
```

Name should be the serial # of your motherboard and IdentifyingNumber is probably blank, but it might be an additional sub-serial #.

Answer (score 0):

Many non-OEM / independent manufacturers (e.g. ASUS) will display the motherboard model number at boot time.