# Find the model of my motherboard without opening the computer

Tags: windows-xp, motherboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find out what the motherboard on my computer is](https://superuser.com/questions/175213/find-out-what-the-motherboard-on-my-computer-is)

I need to find the model of my motherboard so I can find what soundcard/chip it uses so I can get some drivers for it.

Is there anyway to get this from inside XP? I looked through device manager but haven't seen anything that would tell me.

I built the system over a year ago and don't have any receipts to check what it was.