# Two monitor, one with DVI-D connection, the other with VGA?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, vga, dvi

I have a problem.

I have a SyncMaster SA300 (TFT, main monitor) monitor and a SyncMaster 591s (CRT) monitor. I want to use both monitors and share the desktop.

My video card have a VGA port and and a DVI-D dual link port. The main monitor have the same ports.

So, I connected the main monitor trough DVI-D to PC (with a cable) and the other monitor trough VGA (with a cable).

The other monitor works fine, but the main monitor doesn't show nothing. When I connected the main monitor trough DVI-D and VGA port (together), the digital screen worked perfectly.

My problem is that I can't connect the main monitor only by DVI-D dual link, else I have to connect it by DVI-D and VGA, then I can't connect other monitor by VGA.

Can somebody help me? Thank you!!

Comment: Operating system? Also, it is unlikely the monitor uses both links simultaneously, which one does it report as the active one (as in, does the monitor say it's using a digital link or an analog one? Or whatever that particular monitor's terminology may be)

Comment: I use Linux (ArchLinux) and Windows 7. I'm sure that it is not a problem of the OS.

Comment: Does the TFT monitor work just using just the DVI cable?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is an issue with your DVI port if you cannot make your monitor work when only using that port. Although I doubt it there might be an option in the vendor specific graphics card drivers that disable the DVI port.
Otherwise it may be that your graphics card is somewhat broken.
It might be a good idea to try to connect another monitor to the DVI port to see if it is working (if you dont have any you can still use any HDMI capable device, there are simple adapters from DVI to HDMI and vice versa)

Comment: I tried with other monitor (smiliar to my main monitor) and happened the same.

Comment: I tried with other monitor similar to my main monitor. It doesn't work too.

Then, my problem is my video card. I have an Intel HD OnBoard and my motherboard is Gigabyte.

Do you have some idea for solving this problem? Thanks!!

Comment: If the problem persists even with another monitor it is unlikely that it is anything except the graphics card (might be a defect cable if you've used the same for both).

The next step would be to try to get you're hands on a graphics card that you can plug into your computer to see if it helps. 

Additionally it could prove useful to get the exact mainboard name and check the manual for multi monitor output capabilities (refer to this for help: http://superuser.com/questions/175213/find-out-what-the-motherboard-on-my-computer-is ).