# Determine part/ model numbers & specs of Motherboard, Memory & CPU for network of PCs

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, specifications

Is there some easy way to pull this information from a network of PCs?

To this individually on a machine here are the ways:

[How can I find out what motherboard is in my computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/175213/how-can-i-find-out-what-motherboard-is-in-my-computer)

http://www.nextofwindows.com/4-ways-to-find-out-whats-the-motherboard-model-inside-your-windows-7-machine

I would rather avoid going to each machine to get this information. Be able to collect all of the data over the network and put it together in a list/ spreadsheet and/ or clear GUI.

PS: I have Admin access over the network.

Comment: Use [psexec](http://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html) to run the `wmic` commands remotely on each machine.

Comment: Although off topic, falling under corporate network and software recommendations rules, there are multiple softwares intended for asset management and inventory purposes in a LAN or Domain, such as Lansweeper or Open-Audit, but Google would probably be your friend here more than Superuser.