# How much maximum Ram I can have per slot?

Tags: memory, motherboard

How much maximum Ram I can have per slot for desktops and laptops?

Which parameters defines that?

**Update**

if the motherboard with 4 slots support 64GB of Ram, is that true that i can have maximum of 16GB Ram per slot?

Comment: Check the documentation for you motherboard.

Comment: There are too many answers to this question and all of them depend on whether it is a desktop or laptop, what processor is fitted and what the manufacturer decided to wire up.

Comment: Your update turns this into a simple arithmetic question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These would depend on your motherboard.

On Unices, commands such as `dmidecode` would help you identify what hardware you're working with. Without knowing such, we can't tell.

Not being familiar with Windows, I can point you to: [How can I find out what motherboard is in my computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/175213/how-can-i-find-out-what-motherboard-is-in-my-computer)

---

As of Z170-A, you would find the exact specs on Asus website (https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Z170-A/specifications/). As suggested already in the comments, it is limited to 64GB of DDR4.

Comment: This is correct, different motherboards have different chipsets that can have different values. Modern computers from 2015 and up can handle 8GB RAM per slot, exception would be small tablets and netbooks.

Comment: @Peter how about ASUS Z170-A motherboard? it has 4 slots and support 64GB !!

Comment: If it supports 64 GB, the logical conclusion here is that each slot can use 16GB modules.  I haven't seem 16GB sticks in stores, only online and very expensive.